# Using gmaps4rails, all is well, except there's this circular background in the middle of the map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I've tried changing the backgroundColor property to either transparent, none, or white, but it doesn't solve the issue. I've tried it on both chrome and firefox but still the same.

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
  });
</script>
```

Controller:

```
def index
  @foobars = Foobar.all
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@foobars) do |foobar, marker|
    marker.lat foobar.latitude
    marker.lng foobar.longitude
  end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd bet $100 those "circles" are the individual Google Maps image tiles with a large border radius.

Look in your CSS for any `img` styles that have a `border-radius` property that might affect this, and adjust your selectors as necessary. Your browser's devtools can help you locate the offending selector.

Comment: Wow! You're absolutely correct. I've had set an img's border-radius to 100%. I just now need to style it in specific. Thanks!

Comment: How did you found out that it's the `border-radius` that's causing this circles?

Comment: Having used Google Maps before, I've noticed that the individual image tiles load in one-by-one. And I know the `border-radius` trick is useful for creating circular-masked images. From there it was 1+1=2. :)

Comment: Also, the Chrome devtools (Firefox and Safari have them too) are often my first stop when encountering weird issues like this. You can inspect each page element to figure out exactly what's going on. Check it out if you don't use it already.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of and use chrome devtools a lot. It's just that I didn't expect that the cause of my problem is the `border-radius` :)